# Gulp Watch Customizado

Tags: javascript, gulp

Este é meu Gulpfile atual e como estou utilizando-o muito, gostaria de criar um GULP WATCH que realizasse os uglify sempre que os arquivos fossem alterados.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pump = require('pump');

gulp.task('compress', function (cb) {
  console.log("Compressing the Source");
  pump([
        gulp.src('source/*.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('assets/js')
    ]
  );
  console.log("Source Compressed");
  console.log("Compressing AngularJS");
  pump([
        gulp.src('bower_components/angular/angular.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('assets/js')
    ]
  );
  console.log("Compressing AngularJS Animate");
  pump([
        gulp.src('bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('assets/js')
    ],
    cb
  );
});
```

Dicas para melhorar o processo também serão bem-vindas.

Comment: Não lembro de cabeça os esquemas do gulp, mas tenta criar uma nova task com o(s) watch(ers), tipo: `gulp.task('watch', function() { gulp.watch('',['compress'])} )` qualquer coisa complemento, ou vejo a forma mais correta chegando em casa.

Comment: Vou dar umas testadas mas agradeço se puder complementar sim

Comment: hm, nunca usei o Bower, mas ele já não puxa os arquivos certos e minificados?  o que você quer deles é só tirar da pasta do bower e jogar na `assets/js` né?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como já dito no comentário, para criar o *"watch"* é necessário apenas criar uma nova *task*
contendo um `gulp.watch` das *tasks* que você quer que sejam executadas ao modificar o arquivo:

```
gulp.task('watch', () => gulp.watch(
    ['caminho/do_arquivo.js', 'outro_caminho.js'], 
    ['task1', 'task2' ]
))
```

Percebi que todos os seus arquivos javascript estão indo para o mesmo lugar `assets/js`, então seria uma boa criar apenas
uma única *task* para esses arquivos e usar uma *array* no `.src`, pois fica mais fácil caso queira colocar um *sass* ou algo do tipo depois.
E como o caminho deve ser repetido no *watch*, uma outra dica é usar uma variável com os caminhos ao invés de digitá-las 2 vezes.

Resultando em:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pump = require('pump');

var jspaths = [
    'source/*.js',
    'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
    'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    // Se quiser todos os arquivos dentro de "bower_components" (não recomendo) pode usar
    // 'bower_components/**/*.js',
];

gulp.task('jscompress', (cb) => {
    pump([
        gulp.src(jspaths),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('assets/js')
    ], cb);
});


gulp.task('watch', () => gulp.watch(jspaths, [
    'jscompress'
]))
```

Aí é só dar `gulp watch` no `console` e ser feliz! xD

Ou você pode mudar o nome da task `gulp.task('watch',...` por `gulp.task('default',...` e apenas digitar `gulp` no *console*.

Uma observação foi que removi os *logs*, eles são desnecessários considerando que o próprio gulp informará quais *task* iniciaram e terminaram.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta mais que completa, além da melhoria que tu propôs, um muitíssimo obrigado!